# Java print date and time of every input

Tags: java, datetime, java.util.scanner, current-time

I want an output of something like this

```
hi 2022.11.06 12:08:50 pm
hello 2022.11.06 12:09:40 pm
```

but I keep getting

```
hi 2022.11.06 12:08:50 pm
hello 2022.11.06 12:08:50 pm
```

even though I do the next input after a time interval.

```java
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

Date dNow = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dtformat = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss a");

for (int x = 0; x <= 5; x++){ 
    String obj = reader.nextLine();
    System.out.println(obj + dtformat.format(dNow));
}
```

I want an output of something like this

```
hi 2022.11.06 12:08:50 pm
hello 2022.11.06 12:09:40 pm
```

Comment: What do you think the significance of the parameter you pass to `format` is?

Comment: isn't that to format the date and time?

Comment: My question is why you think that calling `dtformat.format(dNow)` twice with exactly the same `dNow` ought to give you different values?   Please read the javadoc for the `Date()` constructor carefully.   *"Allocates a `Date` object and initializes it so that it represents **the time at which it was allocated**, measured to the nearest millisecond."*

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` or `LocalDateTime` and also `DateTimeFormatter`; all are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Declare `private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss a", Locale.UK);`. Substitute your desired locale or `Locale.getDefault()`. After reading each line do `System.out.println(obj + ' ' + ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(FORMATTER));` to get output like `hi 2022.11.06 11:31:23 am` where the time will be current and different each time.

Answer (score 3):

Java is, like most programming languages, imperative.

```
int x = 5;
int y = x;
```

does **not** mean that 'y' is an alias for 'x'. It simply means: Resolve the expression `x`, and take whatever that **currently** resolves to, then update the value of `y` to be that value. Resolving expression `x` simply means: What is the *current* value of this variable.

in other words:

```java
int x = 5;
int y = x;
x = 4;
System.out.println(y);
```

This prints **5**. It does not print 4.

In your code, you resolve the expression `new Date()` exactly once, at the very start, and never again. `dNow` is set in stone once you ran it, and doesn't update. Simply rerun `dNow = new Date();` to update.

NB: This is obsolete, broken API; you should be using the `java.time` package types, such as `LocalDateTime`, and the `java.time` formatters (`DateTimeFormatter`). The old stuff conflates human reckoning with computer reckoning, and thus fails when timezone definitions change. Which they do, every day.

Comment: @user16320675 I see what you mean, but I don’t think it would add something essential here. You are correct, theoretically the OP could fix it by setting `dNow.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());` before printing. IMO this says more about how confusing the `Date` class is and easy to misuse. It contributes in no good way to answering the question as asked.

Comment: @user16320675 At some point I'm writing half a core java tutorial in an answer where I already went out on a bit of a limb (justifiably so, I'd argue) to assume this is the thing OP didn't fully grasp.